# Connection for android and SOAP api

Tags: android, api, soap

I am new developer for SOAP , so guide me how can i call soap api in android.
Here is method which i found but dont know how it works. I have downloaded [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ksoap2-android/downloads) library

```
 public static String connectSOAP(String url, String soapNamespace, String soapAction, String soapMethod, Hashtable<String, String> HT) {

        String result = null;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(soapNamespace, soapMethod);

        if (HT != null) {
            Enumeration<String> en = HT.keys();
            while (en.hasMoreElements()) {

                Object k = en.nextElement();
                Object v = HT.get(k);
                request.addProperty(k.toString(), v);
                System.out.println("key = " + k.toString() + "; value = " + v);
            }
        }


        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
                new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        //envelope.bodyOut = request;
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
        //envelope.getResponse();


        try {

            androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);

            if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {

                result = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;


            } else {

                SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                result = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is method which i want to use as an api call but dont know how can i use this.
so please help me.

Comment: [Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242) you will get step by step instruction .

Comment: okay thank you @sodhankit. I will back to this point if i have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

In using soap webservice, i would highly recommend you not to use any library to make the soap request. Using the classes provided by android is way more convenient and less prone to errors. This is how you make a soap request without use of libraries: First of all you will need to know how to make use of SOAP Ui which is a windows application. You can import your wsdl file here and if it's syntax us correct, then you will get a screen showing the request body for your webservice. You can enter test values and you will get a response structure. This link will guide you on how to use soap ui https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html

Now on to the androiod code :

We will create a class named runTask which extends async task and use http to send the request body and get request response :

```
 private class runTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private String response;
        String string = "your string parameter"
        String SOAP_ACTION = "your soap action here";

        String stringUrl = "http://your_url_here";
        //if you experience a problem with url remove the '?wsdl' ending



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                        //paste your request structure here as the String body(copy it exactly as it is in soap ui)
                        //assuming that this is your request body


                String body = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">" +
                                "<soap:Body>"+
                                "<GetCitiesByCountryResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">"+
                                "<GetCitiesByCountryResult>"+string+"</GetCitiesByCountryResult>"+
                                "</GetCitiesByCountryResponse>"+
                                "</soap:Body>"+
                                "</soap:Envelope>";


                try {
                    URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION);

                    //push the request to the server address

                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.write(body);
                    wr.flush();

                    //get the server response

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {


                        builder.append(line);
                        response = builder.toString();//this is the response, parse it in onPostExecute

                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    try {

                        reader.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response;
        }

        /**
         * @see AsyncTask#onPostExecute(Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {



           try {

              Toast.makeText(this,"Response "+ result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Now just execute the class and watch the magic happen:

```
runTask runner = new runTask();
runner.execute();
```

After getting your response, you can parse it using DOM or SAX parse,some little research and you will understand how to parse. You can create the WSDL webservice using java, and preferable Eclipse Ide. Tutorials are also available on youtube on the WSDL webservices.

Feel free to ask for clarification where the solution is not clear.